# Function not recreating Bitmap from location in memory

Tags: android, bitmap

I have this code:

```
    Bitmap readBitmapImage() {
        String imageInSD = "/sdcard/mac/"+strURL;

        BitmapFactory.Options bOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD,bOptions);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

The decodeFile function returns a null value, which is assigned to bitmap. Why doesn't decodeFile return the Bitmap image of the file saved on the SDCard?

I am working with AndroidStudio.

Comment: That probably isn't the file path to the image, guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your image path, i think it's not returning the absolute path. So try to use this for getting your **imageInSD** path like below

```
String imageInSD=new File(getFilesDir(), "test.png").getAbsolutePath();
```

Here test.png is your image name and make sure it is present in your filepath.

Don't forget to add these permissions in your manifest while dealing with the sdcard

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```